# Add a Placeholder Title For A WordPress Page Template

Tags: php, html, wordpress, templates

I have a basic raw HTML block on wordpress I want it to display this sentence in h2 and centered:

```
Hi my name is Gerard and I am "an engineer"
```

Then I want "an engineer" to change to "a maker" and "an entrepreneur" etc. How is this function called? How can I implement such thing?

An example is currently on display at: www.shapeways.com main slider.

Comment: Just use a placeholder variable for the job title and set it via a custom post variable.

Answer (score 1):

Use Advanced Custom Fields and add a Text custom field to the Page post type -- something like "Header Text", save as `header_text`.

Then in template it's just `the_field('header_text');`

Answer (score 0):

They are utilising the css animation. You can inspect the element and you will see:

```
<div class='sw--rotate-words'>
    <span>Designers</span>
    <span>Engineer</span>
    <span>Makers</span>
    ...
</div>
```

Css:

```
.sw--rotate-words {
    animation:adjustWidth 25s ease-out infinite 0s;
}
```

That creates the animation.